# Can we utilize GA data instead of Sitecore xDB for personalization?

Tags: personalization

We are currently using Google Analytics in the website. We would like to apply personalization on the website based on user behavior. Can we utilize GA Data for executing Sitecore Personalize rules? Example: If user visit specific content related to electronic product which is getting tracked in GA then in next visit that user should view home banner related to electronics product. Can we set Persona and rule in Sitecore which will utilize GA data? or is xDB must for this?

Answer (score 3):

From what I know there is no way to ask Google Analytics engine to get historical data for a single user which currently visits your site.

Sitecore personalization uses historical information of a contact which is stored in xDB. At any time, one site can get that data and execute actions based on it.

It's not possible with GA to get that data. So the answer is: no, you cannot personalize utilizing GA data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So basically we have to use both GA and xDB. GA as business is using currently for reporting and analysis and xDB for personalization.

Comment: Sitecore analytics and google analytics are 2 different things. There are many differences. I won't copy from other sources, but have a look at https://www.google.com/search?q=how+is+sitecore+analytics+different+from+google